# SSH .NET Session handling in multiple winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ssh

I have created a desktop application. The application connects to a 'solaris' server using ssh .net library and runs jobs and utilities as per the user's choice. The utilities and the jobs are coded in perl and c++ in the server. What I am doing now is :- I have a login form, which takes the users credentials and tries to make a connection with the server. If the connection succeeds, it closes the ssh session and moves on to another form which has the list of utilities and jobs to run. Whatever job/utility the user chooses to run, the application takes it to its corresponding form. The user inputs the required data and runs the utility. Now, my application again creates a connection with the same 'solaris' server and then runs the job there. Once the job completes, the connection is automatically closed.

The problem is, A user might need to run multiple different jobs together, for each job a separate connection would be built each time and the job would be run separately. Apart from the extra time it takes to connect, it would mean multiple open connections to the server.

Question :- Since I am already taking user credentials in the login form and connecting to the same server to verify the connection, can I not continue with the same connection till the time the application is closed. In this way I would not need to connect separately for each individual job and would save a considerable amount of time.

I tried some very stupid things like passing the SshClient object to the constructor of the called forms for each job, but it didn't work. I tried to pass it as ref but ref doesn't work on it and throws error. Could anybody tell me how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

SSH basically connects you to the command line (or shell) of a remote machine. Within SSH, you can execute more than one command at a time, either waiting for one to finish before starting another, or running multiple in parallel. See more information here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63648/how-to-send-many-commands-to-shell-and-wait-for-the-command-behind-ends

I think the best bet would be to use this solution on the Solaris side, as opposed to trying to make a a C# solution. You have the ability to log in via SSH, and you need to run multiple commands - that functionality is already present in SSH (or BASH).

Comment: I know.. I am doing just that wherever its possible. But the jobs I am talking about are completely different and require different sets of conditioning, so  I cannot run them together or one after the other just like that. There is no guarantee that one job would be run after another one, it depends on the user's requirement. Also, the spec doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "different sets of conditioning"? Are you talking about different users being logged in via SSH? CD'ing to different directories? Regarding "...no guarantee that one job would be run after another one...", is it not possible to issue different commands in different orders, depending on user input?

Comment: It is possible but that's not the requirement. That is not what the spec demands. The application is a toolbox which should have different forms for different utilities. Whatever utility the user wants to run, he should be able to run only that utility from a dedicated form. The requirement is more to do with the aesthetics then what we can or cannot do. Moreover, i have more than 30 utilities, If I clutter one single form with so many controls for a user to choose what exactly he wants to run then I don't think that is visually or usability wise a very clever thing to do.

Comment: So from that description, it sounds like an aesthetic issue - you want users to be able to fill out multiple forms, and each one would result in a separate command to a server, executed over SSH. In that case, perhaps a "point-of-sale" design might benefit you - a user can fill out multiple forms, each added to a "receipt", and at the end they can "checkout", or execute the whole receipt. If that's not possible, that I'm not really sure what you're asking - the ability to "reuse" SSH is built-in, given that you can execute multiple commands. But if you can't...what advice are you looking for?